# How does If statement works in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, logic, logical-operators

When a user makes a purchase, I want the site to look for this cookie on my Receipt page and if it's present, then the tag should have `'FIREuni' : 'TRUE'`. If the cookie is not present, the tag should have `'FIREuni' : 'FALSE'`. But I don't know weather I am using the if statements in the right way. I am fairly new to javascript this is probably my first code, can anybody help me telling where I am making a mistake?

```
function checkCookie() {
    var src=getCookie("src");
    if (src!="") {
        FIREuni:'TRUE'
        var TrackObject = {

            'CJ' : {

                'CID': '12346',
                'TYPE': '7865',
                'OID': 'ORDERNUMBER',
                'CURRENCY':'USD',
                'DISCOUNT': '',
                'COUPON': '',

                PRODUCTLIST : [

                    {   'ITEM': 'item.variant.sku',
                        'AMT': 'OTOTAL',
                        'QTY': 'OTY'
                    },
                    {   'ITEM': 'item.variant.sku',
                        'AMT': 'OTOTAL',
                        'QTY': 'OTY'
                    }
                ]
            }};

    }
    else
    {
        FIREuni:'FALSE'
        var TrackObject ={


            'UNI' : {

                'CID': '',
                'TYPE': '',
                'OID': '',
                'CURRENCY': '',
                'DISCOUNT': '',
                'COUPON': '',

                PRODUCTLIST : [

                    {   'ITEM': '',
                        'AMT': '',
                        'QTY': ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? What do you want? Your question states "how does an if statement work" or how is it compiled. Please be more clear

Comment: What is `FIREuni` supposed to be? Is it a property of the `TrackObject` object? Is it another variable? By itself it's meaningless.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I thought the same thing, but it's not a syntax error. It's a statement label followed by a statement that's just a string literal.

Comment: So it's valid syntax, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: And why is your function assigning a local variable and then not doing anything with it?

Comment: FIREuni is trackobject's object, I have other script in other page which will run when the FIREuni is true and will do nothing when FIREuni is false. But how do I set FIREuni to TRUE or FALSE here?

Comment: @Barmar, ah yea I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the conditional (`if`/`else`) correctly, but you have some syntax errors in how you are setting the value of FIREuni. Conditionals work by evaluating the expression that you pass to them, if the expression evaluates to something truthy (which can pretty much anything other than `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `''`, `void 0`, or `0`) then the block of code that follows will be executed, otherwise it will move on to the next `else if` or `else` if they are present.

When setting values outside of an object, you should use `=`, not `:`. So it should be:

```
FIREuni = true;
```

or `FIREuni = false` in the else condition.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your getCookie method returns null if the cookie isn't found.  In JS null and "" are not the same thing.  You should check if(src !=== null).

Depending on your getCookie function, you may have to check for null, undefined, and/or "".

Comment: How do you know what his `getCookie` function returns?

Comment: The getCookie code was not posted, but looking a common getCookie implementations, they return null. 
And yes I had a typo.

Comment: @Barmar I have set a cookie named src with its value as uni on my home, so if that cookie is not present then I want FIREuni to be false.

Comment: @Programmermid If you're answering my comment to your question, you should post it as a comment on the question or update the question. Comments down here should only be related to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comment: "FIREuni is trackobject's object [...] "

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
var TrackObject;

function checkCookie() {
    var src = getCookie("src");

    if (src) {

        TrackObject = {

            FIREuni : true,

            'CJ' : {

                'CID': '12346',
                'TYPE': '7865',
                'OID': 'ORDERNUMBER',
                'CURRENCY':'USD',
                'DISCOUNT': '',
                'COUPON': '',

                PRODUCTLIST : [

                    {   'ITEM': 'item.variant.sku',
                        'AMT': 'OTOTAL',
                        'QTY': 'OTY'
                    },
                    {   'ITEM': 'item.variant.sku',
                        'AMT': 'OTOTAL',
                        'QTY': 'OTY'
                    }
                ]
            }};

    }
    else {

        TrackObject = {

            FIREuni : false,

            'UNI' : {

                'CID': '',
                'TYPE': '',
                'OID': '',
                'CURRENCY': '',
                'DISCOUNT': '',
                'COUPON': '',

                PRODUCTLIST : [

                    {   'ITEM': '',
                        'AMT': '',
                        'QTY': ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit but will this check for a cookie named src first and then if its present it will set FIREuni = true and populate all the values within CJ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you defined your `getCookie` function, but if the value of `src` is anything other than an empty string, false, null, undefined, or NaN, it will pass.

Answer (score -1):

It seems in your code FIREuni is a global variable that is being modified from within the `function checkCookie()`. It is possible to this if somewhere where you opened the  tag, you declared it explicitely as `var FIREuni;`, or `VAR FIREuni = false;` or `var FIREuni = TRUE; depending on the default value you want it to have or if you want it to be null before any validation is done. About your specific question, the if is correct in your case, is just a matter of`
if(condition){
}else{
}`
and your condition seems to come from another function that checks if a cookie named src is set in the client's machine.

I wouldn't though recommend you to use the approach you are using, eventhough is fine, I wouldn't set a global variable if the cookie is set with the function you are using, but I would move the whole code that is creating the object in case it is set or not, to the `function getCookie()`, and then, whenever you need to check if the cookie is set, call this function, and if the object is initialized leave as it is, and if it is not do whatever you should do, I mean, put it all in blank, or initialize it with the user's values. That would be more efficient in my opinion and wouldn't be using global variables which is confusing, time consuming and some times not a good practice.

Comment: As @Barmar already pointed out in the comments `FIREuni` is not a variable - its a statement label.

Comment: @Juan can you suggest a code for what you are saying? Syntax is hard for me since I am really new at Javascript.